# Breakline in UIButton title

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uibutton

in the following button is an address showed. My problem is the addresses are very long and how can i get between the two variables in the title of the button an breakline??

```
NSString *sitz = map.kordinate.herkunft;
NSString *strasse = map.kordinate.strasse;
NSString *strasseMitKomma = [strasse stringByAppendingString:@","];
NSString *fertigesSitzFeld = [strasseMitKomma stringByAppendingString:sitz];
UIButton *firmensitz = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

the breakline must be between strasseMitKomma and sitz??

thank you for helping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must configure the UILabel inside the UIButton to support multiple line.
You can do it like this:

```
 NSString *address;

    address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,\n%@", @"street name", @"city name"];   // Note the \n after the comma, that will give you a new line

    addressButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];


    [addressButton.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    // Enabling multiple line in a UIButton by setting the line break mode
    [addressButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

    [addressButton setTitle:address forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

By the way, you don't need so many NSString variables. You could have put the result of the new string in the NSString variable you were already using.
Have a look at the method stringWithFormat in the first line of my answer. Read the [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:) for more detail.

Comment: UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap is deprecated (iOS 6.0). Use NSLineBreakByCharWrapping instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked on iOS9.

```
[_butNoReceipt.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
[_butNoReceipt.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[_butNoReceipt setTitle:btnTest forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```