# Multiple Lines in UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

Hi I have problem for set multiple lines to my Button which is declared like that:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.titleLabel.font            = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode   = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines   = 0;
button.titleLabel.shadowOffset    = CGSizeMake (1.0, 0.0);

[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(myButtonClick) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 317.0, 100.0);
[button setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
button.titleLabel.font            = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
button.titleLabel.text = @"ahoj";

NSMutableString *ObratString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:button.titleLabel.text];

[ObratString appendString:@"\n"];
[ObratString appendString:@"caw"];
[ObratString appendString:@"\n"];
[ObratString appendString:@"helllo"];
button.titleLabel.text = ObratString;
[ObratString release];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

But in the end I just see the first line.
Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265940/breakline-in-uibutton-title

Comment: See another question and some answers about this - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `UIButton` displays it's text with a contained `UILabel`. The default for the contained label is to display one line of text only. This label is accessible through the `titleLabel` property, and anything you can do to a normal label can be done to it.

For example making it multi-lines broken by words:

ObjC:

```
myButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Dynamic number of lines
myButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Swift:

```
myButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0; // Dynamic number of lines
myButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;
```

Comment: Yeah but if you can see I made it it is in my code but it just wont do wat it has to

Comment: UILineBreakModeWordWrap is deprecated. use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping instead

Answer (score 4):

Swift version for the checked response:

```
    myButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    myButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```